# How do you uninstall rbenv on macOS?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

How do you uninstall rbenv on macOS? My version of rbenv is messed up, and `brew uninstall rbenv` isn't working because brew relies on ruby.

Comment: The official Rbenv documentation contains a section on [uninstalling rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I took these steps to successfully get rid of rbenv on my mac running El Capitan (10.11.4). Rbenv is a major cause of `Failed to build gem native extension errors` from my experience.

- Remove using brew: `brew remove rbenv`
- Delete `.rbenv` directory: `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`

***For Bash***

- Open `.bash_profile` file and delete any lines with rbenv in them: `vi ~/.bash_profile`
- Open `.bashrc` file and delete any lines with rbenv in them: `vi ~/.bashrc`

Finally, reload `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`:

> . ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bashrc

***For ZShell***

- Open `.zprofile` file and delete any lines with rbenv in them
- Open `.zshrc` file and delete any lines with rbenv in them

Finally, reload `.zprofile` and `.zshrc`:

> . ~/.zprofile && . ~/.zshrc

Comment: How to remove a line in vim? Use `dd` to delete an entire line.

Comment: This tip solved my problem involving Heroku on High Sierra! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: use nano instead of vim, for novice users like me

Comment: I did this and now `/usr/bin/ruby` is unresponsive

Comment: What about /opt/rbenv?  Does that belong to the OS, or did brew put that stuff there?

Comment: I was running into CA certs problem with rbenv managed ruby version 2.3.1, and tried to update to 2.7.2 but kept failing. I switch my ruby version with homebrew, and the CA certs problem went away. Thanks!

Comment: On newer macOS versions with `zsh` being the default shell, you may want to delete the `rbenv`-related lines from `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 17):

I think you should be able to uninstall rbenv by simply removing `~/.rbenv`.

```
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
```

Or, if you installed rbenv via Homebrew, you can do

```
rm -rf `brew --prefix`/Cellar/rbenv
```

Comment: What about ``rm -rf `brew --prefix`/Cellar/ruby`` and ``rm -rf `brew --prefix`/Cellar/ruby-build``? I’m pretty sure I only installed ruby-build because rbenv prompted me to.

Answer (score 8):

Remember to uninstall all ruby versions installed by `rbenv` before uninstalling `rbenv` itself.

```rb
rbenv versions
rbenv uninstall x.y.z # uninstall all versions from the last step
brew uninstall rbenv
```