# OSX Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, homebrew, rbenv

Hi there ive been searching for a fix on stackexchange and google for a long time and without success, so i thought id give up and ask this question since it seems to have not been covered on other topics.

Im having the following message appear when i try to initiate a rails server (which did work before, i just dont know how i broke it)

`Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3`

**A bit of context: im on OSX, with `rbenv` installed via `homebrew`.**

`$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.3 (set by /Users/<user>/.rbenv/version)`

ok, so `rbenv` is installed and has the right version.

`echo $PATH
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/shims:/Users/<user>/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin :`

$PATH is there and i have the following on `~./bash_profile`
`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

*ok so whats the problem?* you ask? because i have the following thrown back at me:

`$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby`

now, this last bit have me hope, it seems im using OSX's built in ruby and not the one from `rbenv`so i did a `gem env`

`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/bronze/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/<user>/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/<user>/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/<user>/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin`

i have found no paths i could take at this point. for me it seems all is installed but OSX doesnt see the `shims` or whatever from `rbenv`

`$ which -a ruby
/usr/bin/ruby`

this should have showed the `rbenv` installation, right?

any and all help is much appreciated at this time.

-cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please run `rbenv init` per the [instructions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: i did. `rbenv init` and `rbenv rehash`, init gives me ```rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"```

Comment: yes, ive seen a couple ways of adding it but this is what i got ```### There from beginning
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
### Added by Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
#Rbenv adding
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"```

Comment: link to a gist better formatted with .bash_profile https://gist.github.com/bronze/1f5395b27bd5974a91811a2d4fea9744

Comment: update: uninstalled homebrew and rbenv and reinstalled from scratch, now it finds ruby ```which -a ruby
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby``` but `gem env` still doesnt see the rbenv dir

Answer (score 0):

Ok this has been a wild trip so if anyone finds this question in the future, this is what worked: **uninstall everything**

`` brew uninstall rbenv
brew uninstall ruby-build
rm -rf `brew --prefix`/Cellar/rbenv `` as per [How do you uninstall rbenv on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173968/how-do-you-uninstall-rbenv-on-osx)

then i also uninstalled homebrew. a bit drastic but nothing was working anyway...

so, starting from scratch, installing homebrew, then rbenv, then the right version, and the `shims` path started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

RVM gives you gemsets, which are sandboxed environments that let you maintain separate sets of gems.

`$ rvm gemset use global`
this should return:

`gemsets for ruby-2.x.x =>
(default)
 global`

```
$ rvm gemset use global
$ gem list
```

done!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your global or local version with rbenv? `rbenv global 2.2.3`

By using the `global` every project will have ruby 2.2.3 available.
If you want to only use this version in the current folder: `rbenv local 2.2.3`