# While installing RVM, it is returning a WARNING: Above files contains PATH= with no $PATH inside, this can break RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, path, rvm

#### The problem explanation

I am running OS X for Apple Silicon - Mac M1, using `.zshrc` shell (not bash), and trying to install RVM following the below instructions to contribute to the open-source project:

1. Install gpg using Homebrew to verify the integrity of the RVM installer.
   `brew install gpg`
   `brew doctor`
   And got `Your system is ready to brew.` which seems that I successfully added it.
2. Download the public key for the RVM installer.
   `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`
   and I am not getting any error, also seems to be successful.
3. To install RVM and the latest version of ruby and rails, which is probably a good idea, use the following command.
   `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enable`
   which is returning the following with ***Warning at the end**:

```
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan 15 23:46:22 2021 +05
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.12.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.mkshrc /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bashrc /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.zshrc /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/ is complete.
/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile:2:export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile:5:export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile:6:export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile:7:export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

  * WARNING: Above files contains PATH= with no $PATH inside, this can break RVM,
    for details check https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525
    to avoid this warning prepend $PATH


Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate
```

4. As a final step to verify that everything went well.
   `type rvm | head -1`
   which shall return `rvm is a function`.
   But, I am getting `rvm is a shell function from /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/scripts/cli`

#### My script (source) files

*1. ~/.bash_profile*

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

*2. ~/.bashrc*

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

*3. ~/.zshrc*

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

#### Taken actions to resolve it:

I came across the following [solution](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525) by @elado back in 2012, and I tried to change my first export PATH `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` to `export PATH=$PATH:"$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` but I am still getting the same output with same *warning when I run  `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enable`.

So, could anyone advise how I can resolve the issues (in my view) in steps number 3 and 4?

*Originally posted by @SarvarKh in https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-956250296*

### EDIT #1

***Warning at step number 3 was resolved** after pretending `$PATH:` in `.bash_profile`.
Updated `.bash_profile` file:

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

#### !However

I am still getting `rvm is a shell function from /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/scripts/cli` after running `type rvm | head -1` instead of getting `rvm is a function`

Comment: Hope this question will help many macOS users willing to install RVM because I have encountered this issue and have not been able to figure it out for while now. I had created an issue in the RVM repo in GitHub, but no reply was received yet.

Comment: I think the warning is fairly clear. Since the first 4 do not contain $PATH you are actually just overwriting the PATH variable over and over rather than extending it. e.g. `export HELLO=1 && export HELLO=2 && echo $HELLO # 2` because the second export overwrites the first but `export HELLO=1 && export HELLO=$HELLO:2 && echo $HELLO # 1:2` because the second export prepends the system variable `$HELLO`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks. I have resolved that Warning at step #3. However,
I am still getting `rvm is a shell function from /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/scripts/cli` after running `type rvm | head -1` instead of getting `rvm is a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: `rvm is a shell function from ...` sounds right to me. I don't think you should have problems using it with that. However you should really clean up your `PATH` definitions in your `bash_profile`. You're inserting the same path multiple times into your `PATH` variable now. Try `echo $PATH` from the command line and you will see. I suggest to remove the duplicates from your `bash_profile` to clean it up.

Comment: @Casper thanks for your reply. I changed my default shell on the terminal from `zsh` to `bash` running `chsh -s /bin/bash`. After that, I realized that I had rbenv installed some time back in the past as well which was causing $PATH issues, I believe. So after uninstalling it and rerunning step 5 mentioned in the question, I successfully installed and got `rvm is a function` after running `type rvm | head -1`. phew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue was composed of the followings:

**1.** Prepend `$PATH:` in `.bash_profile`. So, my `.bash_profile` looks like this now *(perhaps, it can be cleaned up, but not sure. If you know how to do it, please let me know in the comments or leave a link)*.

```
    source ~/.profile
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
    
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
    
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
    
    export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    
    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
    export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

**2.** I had [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/README.md), installed sometime back, which is another ruby version manager. So, I had to uninstall it following those [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840977/14103174).
*Note: while deleting any lines with `rbenv`, please delete only the part relevant to `rbenv`, not the whole line itself.

For instance, delete `/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:` from:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin
```

**3.** I did change my default shell terminal from `zsh` to `bash` running `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

---

#### RVM successful installation [verification](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#3-reload-shell-configuration-amp-test).

Finally, it is returning `rvm is a function` when you run `type rvm | head -1` as was supposed to.

Comment: This must help, if not please leave a comment. I will try to help and respond as fast as I can, I kind of became master in installing RVM on macOS)