# Find where a specific Ruby version is installed

Tags: ruby, asdf

On Mac, I used to have `rbenv` as Ruby version manager but recently switched to `asdf`. I want to create a Ruby on Rails 7.0.4 but it uses an outdated version and I'd like to locate it.

```bash
$ rails new app
    "Rails 7 requires Ruby 2.7.0 or newer.

    You're running
      ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin"


$ which ruby           
/Users/kawsay/.asdf/shims/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.5p211 (2022-11-24 revision ba5cf0f7c5) [arm64-darwin21]

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "3.0.5"

$ asdf list ruby        
  2.7.4
 *3.0.5

$ brew info ruby      
==> ruby: stable 3.2.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.33
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.5 (2022-11-24 patchlevel 211) [arm64-darwin21]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/kawsay/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/kawsay/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/kawsay/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/kawsay/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/kawsay/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/kawsay/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-21
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/kawsay/.gem
     - /Users/kawsay/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
     - /Users/kawsay/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/kawsay/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.5/bin
     - /Users/kawsay/.asdf/shims
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/bin
     - /Users/kawsay/.cargo/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@2.8/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
     - /opt/homebrew/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin

$ which rbenv
rbenv not found

$ which rvm
rbenv not found
```

How can I find where ruby 2.6.8p205 is installed ?

Comment: Try `which -a ruby`. That lists all rubies on your path. If it's not on your path, use `find / -name ruby -print`.

Comment: Ideed, `/usr/bin/ruby` is the culpable, thanks ! Feel free to write it as an answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue where you have [system Ruby](https://dontusesystemruby.com), brew Ruby, asdf Ruby, and rbenv Ruby. In short, your system is confused about where to find things.

The first step is to remove brew's Ruby installation:

```bash
brew uninstall ruby
```

The second step is to [remove rbenv completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840977/3784008). (or use [the official docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv))

The third step is to make sure that system Ruby does not have the Rails gem installed. Start a shell without loading your profile so that you can bypass asdf and any other configuration:

```bash
env -i bash --norc --noprofile
```

Then confirm it's pointing at system Ruby: (*your version will differ slightly depending on your version of macOS*)

```bash
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
```

Then uninstall the Rails gem:

```bash
gem uninstall rails
```

But while you're at it you might want to remove *all* the gems you installed using system Ruby: (*ignore any errors here*)

```bash
gem uninstall -aIx
```

Now close that shell session and switch back to your default shell. Make sure that your shell profile is cleared of anything related to rbenv and that you have no `GEM_*` environment variables being set. (assuming you use ZSH, check every `~/.zsh*` file and `~/.gemrc`) Then start a new shell session to load the cleaned profiles.

Then make sure asdf has a properly groomed environment:

```bash
asdf reshim
```

Now when you run `gem env` you should see output like this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 patchlevel 0) [arm64-darwin22]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/foo/.gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /opt/homebrew/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/foo/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-22
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
     - /Users/foo/.gem/ruby/3.2.0
```

Note the difference between `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` and `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` in this output and yours. You need to have output that looks like this, otherwise that means that asdf is not installed properly and you should [restart the installation of asdf from the beginning](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html).

Afterwards, re-run `gem install rails` and you should be able to complete `rails new app` successfully.

If not, there is a shortcut to [run commands with asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/core.html#exec) for any given command:

```bash
asdf exec gem install rails
asdf exec rails new app
asdf exec rails server
```

This should bypass everything else and use asdf exclusively.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, I went for the `asdf exec` shortcut. Ideal solution would be to fully reinstall asdf I guess. Thanks for the insights