# when I'm trying to create a new app using `rails new` command it throws this error saying I have ruby version 2.6.x. but my global version 2.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

When I'm trying to create a rails app using `rails new a--name` command. it throws me this error saying I currently have `2.6.10` but when I find out the version I'm using `ruby -v` it still gives me

`ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin22]` as expected. I'm using `rbenv` (just to give you context) I tried finding the reason online but nothing really helped. any help on this would be really helpful.

Here is the screenshot of the list of my rbenv versions

[image]

and my ruby version

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

```
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0

    Rails 7 requires Ruby 2.7.0 or newer.

    You're running
      ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]

    Please upgrade to Ruby 2.7.0 or newer to continue.
```

Comment: Please post the output of these commands: `which ruby`, `which gem`, `which rails`

Comment: try gem uninstall rails, uninstall any version, then make sure your ruby is correct and run gem install rails

Comment: `/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/ruby` this output of `which ruby` I think this is coming out as expected. `which rails` gives this `/usr/bin/rails`.

Comment: @arieljuod I tried uninstalling all versions of rails I have and then checked ruby version it still showed I have 2.7.5 but and then I installed rails back but still it throws me the same error.

Comment: Your system and rbenv executables are mixed. Make sure you are using `/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/gem` to install rails. Your rails executable should be `/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/rails`

Comment: @JanVítek  Any Clue on how do I do that ? sorry if this is a naive question to ask, I'm kind of a beginner to the rails community.

Comment: Need output of `which gem`

Comment: Does an rbenv reshim help to get rails to see the newer version of Ruby?

Comment: @JanVítek Here you go

`/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/gem`

Comment: Then `gem install rails` should install rails for the correct version of ruby, try to run in once again. Anyway you should always be able to run the correct rails with full path `/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/rails new app_name`.

Comment: @JanVítek Still Throws the same. Tried installing rails like the following

```/Users/chn-sridharsai/.rbenv/shims/gem install rails``` 




```Successfully installed rails-7.0.4.2
Parsing documentation for rails-7.0.4.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```


but still throws the same.

Comment: I recommend that you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75378191/3784008 It is for asdf instead of rbenv but generally has sound advice for this type of problem.